# Trying to replace the circular lamp

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, light-bulb

Any idea how to remove the plug encircled below in this picture? This plug is connected to a wire that goes through the ceiling.

Basically I've already taken the screws mounted to the lamp and now the lamp is hanging to the ceiling. I don't wanna break anything and I am stuck on what to do next.

The model is an [Omni LWCL-20WDL](https://www.omniphilippines.com.ph/product/15wd/) circular lamp.

[image]

Comment: Did you try unscrewing the 4 small screws on the bottom right below the plug in the picture?.....after turning off power I hope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Is commonly called a cord grip or CGB. The nut being completely removed will show how the grip functions. Plastic ones usually have a large number of plastic slats that push in on a rubber sleeve.

The connections are most likely under the 4 screws but circle lights are normally connected with a push on fitting . The wires going through the ceiling to junction blocks or wire nuts depending on country.

Answer (score 1):

That does not look like a plug.

It looks like a "**cable gland**" which is a type of strain relief that compresses a rubber (or rubber-like) o-ring or grommet onto the cable which passes through it.

The point of disconnection would be inside the fixture housing that the cable gland attaches to.